# Packet Crafting on a Mac

Tags: netcat, packet-crafting

I think (based on searching the forums), that NetCat is the best option, but wanted to hear if others are preferable.

Anyone have good success with a packet-crafting tool (specifically on Mac)? I've tried HPing, but had some issues. I'm looking into NetCat ('nc' on mac) now, but it's not working as I had thought. Basically, I captured some packets that a remote control sends over a wifi network to turn lights on and off (using X10 controllers), and am looking for a way to replay them by crafting a TCP packet from the command line.

I used Wireshark to sniff the traffic, so I know the package is: DEVICE -sendplc-"C4 DIM 10"

I'm trying: echo 'DEVICE -sendplc-"C4 DIM 10"' > nc 192.168.2.196 6003 but there's no response from the receiving system.

The exact bytestream is (if anyone wants to check that I got the right dataframe): 08004642f1b400260897ad6308004500004b08e240004006aaf5c0a802c1c0a802c4d8d7177399aab39 e57ff4753801880ae37ea00000101080a323353ce01b406424445564943457e73656e64706c637e2243 34204f4e220a

Next step I'm going to check is to make sure the packet arrives exactly by sniffing and compare it to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It is [available](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/portability.html) as a macport or just download, build and install it yourself.

<sup>and, [Scapy at Darwinports](http://scapy.darwinports.com/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Is it not liking the newline echo would append? Have you tried echo -n to leave off the newline?

Answer (score 0):

The standard place to look for packet crafting tools is the Sectools page: [Top 4 Packet Crafting Tools](http://sectools.org/packet-crafters.html). [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) from there is probably the best suited for your needs.

In this case, the new [**nping**](http://nmap.org/nping/man.html) tool from the same source might be an interesting try too.
I see that you are generating an Ethernet IP packet, this should be feasible with [nping](http://nmap.org/nping/).

Answer (score 0):

I realize it was all a unix piping problem. Netcat worked perfectly, I needed to use a | instead of a > to send data to nc.

Thanks, Brad, you gave me the right idea.